# How to remove an array from a Multidimensional array by key if condition is met Php

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-5, foreach

I have a array structured like so

```
array:2 [▼
  "id_1553623907416" => array:2 [▼
    "id_title" => "About"
    "id_content" => """
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <p>Helllo world</p>
      </body>
      </html>
      """
  ]
  "id_1553623916174" => array:2 [▼
    "id_title" => "Education"
    "id_content" => """
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <p>hello data</p>
      </body>
      </html>
      """
  ]
]
```

i need to be able to remove the array named id_1553623907416 if it contains the value About in the sub-array key id_title. The ids are dynamic so this has to be dynamically.

that array is stored in the variable @output.

```
 @foreach ($output as $item)    
   @if($item["id_title"] == "About")
      //remove array 
   @else
     //do something else 
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You could convert your array to a `Collection` and use the `filter()` function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter. If that's too much overhead, use the `unset()` method in the answer below.

Comment: I don't think that is a good approach. Seem you are in blade template? If so - that is bad practice to transform data when you are in View of MVC. The only thing you can apply in view is just skip this item and go for next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your existing code (I don't know Laravel) just expose the key in the `foreach` and `unset`:

```
 @foreach ($output as $key => $item)    
   @if($item["id_title"] == "About")
      unset($output[$key]); 
   @endif
@endforeach
```

If there can be only one then add `break;` after the `unset`.

Or you can filter them out:

```
$output = array_filter($output, function($v) { return $v['id_title'] != 'About'; });
```